# How to interpret HTML generated in PHP in a Magento 2 template

Tags: magento2, php, html

It's difficult to explain with basic sentences so here the code :

**template.phtml**

```
<p id="text"><?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo __('Some text [[REPLACE]]') ?></p>
```

**Javascript**

```
var list = '<ul><li>A</li><li>B</li></ul>';
$("#text").text(function(index, text) {
    return text.replace("[[REPLACE]]", list);
});
```

**Actual outcome**

```
Some text <ul><li>A</li><li>B</li></ul>
```

**Desired outcome**

Some text

- A
- B

It seems that Magento 2 won't interpret HTML generated. Is there a way ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As noted in the [jQuery documentation](http://api.jquery.com/text/) for the .text() method it converts html elements into textual output.

To Quote:

> The code `$( "div.demo-container" ).text( "<p>This is a test.</p>" );`
>   will produce the following DOM output:
>
> `<div class="demo-container">&lt;p&gt;This is a test.&lt;/p&gt;</div>`
>
> It will appear on a rendered page as though the tags were
>   exposed, like this:
>
> `<p>This is a test</p>`

If you wish to append html in this manner it looks like the .html() method is more what you're looking for.

Something like this should work:

```
var list = '<ul><li>A</li><li>B</li></ul>';
$('#text').html($('#text').html().replace('[[REPLACE]]', list));
```